# EA in MQL5 does not follow If condition

Tags: trading, mql5, metatrader5

I am trying to write extremely simple EA in MQL5, which has to follow only one if condition. There is an array that stores the last 5 closing prices. The idea is to open a BUY position when the last 4 closing prices (excluding the current candle) are in uptrend. However the EA starts opening BUY positions one after another without even caring about the condition. I am posting the full code.

I tried to create a new method Uptrend(), which has absolutely the same condition - still does not work.

```
#include <Trade\Trade.mqh>

CTrade trade;


void OnTick()
  {

  double tpoint = Point();
  double ClosePriceArray[];

  ArraySetAsSeries(ClosePriceArray, true);
  CopyClose(Symbol(), PERIOD_CURRENT, 0, 5, ClosePriceArray);

  double Ask = NormalizeDouble(SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(),SYMBOL_ASK),_Digits);
  double Bid = NormalizeDouble(SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(),SYMBOL_BID),_Digits);

  if ((ClosePriceArray[4] < ClosePriceArray[3] < ClosePriceArray[2]< ClosePriceArray[1]) && PositionsTotal() < 1) {
      trade.Buy(0.10, NULL, Ask, (Ask-50*tpoint), (Ask+150*tpoint), NULL);

  }


}
```

I want the EA to open a BUY position only when the condition is met. There are no error messages or compilation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the comparison operators using `&&` and add another condition as below

```
if ((ClosePriceArray[4] < ClosePriceArray[3] && ClosePriceArray[3] < ClosePriceArray[2] && ClosePriceArray[2]< ClosePriceArray[1]) && PositionsTotal() < 1)
{
  trade.Buy(0.10, NULL, Ask, (Ask-50*tpoint), (Ask+150*tpoint), NULL);
}
```

Also you don't need to Normalize the `Bid` and `Ask` prices, they are normalized by default, but you need to Normalize other price values such as tp and sl levels, lot sizes etc.

Comment: That fixed the issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to selected answer. Don't ever use `NormalizeDouble` to normalize prices and volumes, this can lead to unpredictable results.

Prices must always be normalized by tick size:

```
double NormalizePrice(double p)
  {
   double ts=SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_TRADE_TICK_SIZE);
   return(MathRound(p/ts) * ts);
  }
```